# jQuery children not have data attribute type of

Tags: jquery, children

I want to color all the direct `li` children of the first `ul` that do not have a data attribute type of 'land'.

I have the following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fidev/5aF4H/21/) but for some reason it's selecting the children of the sub-menu not the direct children of the nav. Which I though was what `.children()` does.

JS

```
$('.nav').children('li:not(:data-type)').css({
    color: 'blue'
});
```

HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <li data-type="land"><a title="tree" href="#">tree</a>

        <div class="locations-wrapper">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li> <a title="sub-tree-1" href="#">sub-tree-1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a title="sub-tree-2" href="#">sub-tree-2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li data-type="land"><a title="bush"  href="#">bush</a>

        <div class="locations-wrapper">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li> <a title="sub-bush-1" href="#">bush-tree-1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a title="sub-bush-2" href="#">bush-tree-2</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li> <a title="sun" href="#">sun</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a title="clouds" href="#">clouds</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I only want the li list items 'sun' and 'clouds' to be coloured.

Comment: Since I'm not clear, I'll ask. Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5aF4H/19/?

Comment: All your links are inside children of `.nav > ul`, so they'll be colored, too. Why not target `a[title="tree"]`?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, sorry about that, I've updated the code to reflect what the question asked... :/ I only want to colour the list items 'sun' and 'clouds'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('.nav  > ul > li > a:not([data-type="land"])').css({
    color: 'blue'
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5aF4H/19/)**

Comment: thanks! - That worked. I updated with a more sensible choice of colour. For anyone else viewing. http://jsfiddle.net/fidev/5aF4H/33/

Answer (score 2):

Try `.not()` along with [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('.nav').find('li').not("[data-type]").css({
    color: 'blue'
});
```

[**DEmo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/91/)

Also you should use `.find()` instead od `.children()` because `.children()` travere only first level of hierarchy. In your case it wont traverse to `li`

**Edit**

```
$('.nav').find('li a').not("[data-type=land]").css({
    color: 'red'
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/92/)

Comment: Find goes more than one level deep, though.

Comment: @fidev Is this what you want?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - nope. I've updated the code to reflect the question. The data attributes are now on the `li` items

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: data-type

In order to do a *not data-type* you'd have to use the square bracket attribute notation:

```
...not('[data-type]')
```

However there are several other problems with your code:

1. There are no `li` children of `nav`, only `ul` elements.
2. No `li` elements have a `data-type` attribute, only the `a` elements within them do.

Assuming you want to apply this to *any* `a` element contained within the list with no `data-type` attribute, you can simply:

```
$('.nav').children('ul').find('a').not('[data-type]').css({
    color: 'blue'
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5aF4H/20/).

If the `ul` element will always be the only child of your `nav` element, you can drop the `.children('ul')` altogether and just search for any `a` element contained within the `nav`.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I've updated the code to reflect what the question asked. I only want to colour the list items 'sun' and 'clouds'.